# Delete and add buttons that move along with table rows

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, dynamic, scroll

I need a feature similar to the contacts app. When you add a new contact address, a green plus button appears next to the table view to do so. This button moves up and down and is almost locked to that table view cell. But it is 'outside' of the table view.

When you add one address field, the green plus is replaced with the red delete button, which again appears for all rows by the side of the table view, and scrolls together with the table view cells.

How can I replicate this behaviour in my custom app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `UITableView` in **edit mode** you will get it as default by allowing your `UITableView` to Add/Delete the cell from Table,

Here is the tutorial link

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer..Its good, however I wanted the add / delete buttons to be outside the table view..but locked to the cell, if you look at the contacts app, you will know what I mean.